# supported formats in GD to save an image using php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I am working on a script that allow user to convert their images in different formats.
now i have images and i want to save this image in multiple formats i.e. `png`, `jpeg`, `tiff`, `psd`, `jpeg2000` and `BMP` . is this possible in GD if not then what is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the supported file formats by [gd_info](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.gd-info.php) method avilable in gd.GD not support all of these formats you can use imagick instead that support all of your formats